# How to share data between an application (console or service) and a web service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, service

I have the following situation :

- A windows service that crunches data and maintains a data structure representing statistics and such
- A simple REST web service (asp.net webapi)

I would like so that given a web request handled by the mvc.net webapi controller, the data returned is provided by the windows service.

Simply put, I would like to avoid having to use a database only to pass data from the windows service to the web application controller.

The reason is for performance, since it is live data and quite a big amount of it so I want to avoid the bottleneck of real-time database read and writes...

Is that possible?

**Is Redis the only option?**

I would surely appreciate a more '.NET' way of caching data between applications than having to run an Ubuntu machine thru VirtualBox with a Vagrant setup...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)? One of the motivations behind that technology was to provide better performance for [big data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) and [real-time web applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_web)

Comment: NoSQL is pretty broad...I am open to use that paradigm but I don't know which one to choose

Comment: Well, it mostly depends on your business data model (key/value, document, graph, etc). For rapidly changing data with a foreseeable database size (should fit mostly in memory), I would go with [Redis](http://redis.io/). It has a lot of useful and complex operations and works like a charm for real-time analytics.

Comment: @MatiCicero Thanks! Gonna have a look

Comment: No problem at all! Glad I could be of help

Comment: but I am keen to hear others replies also :)

Comment: The Redis project does not officially support Windows. :(

Comment: Oh, that's quite a shame. Are you planning to have the database in a dedicated server or in the same server which is running the web application? Redis can be ran on a separate server with a different OS

Comment: Is WebAPI a necessary service framework for you? If no, give ServiceStack+Redis a shot. ServiceStack is really good way to go with REST services: https://github.com/ServiceStack/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally went the Redis way, thanks to Mati Cicero,
it looks pretty well suited to real-time needs.

I have to use [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/redis) since I am in C#, my only disappointment is that setup could have been simpler (Ubuntu server for Redis, running in a VirtualBox) .

And I hope this setup can hold in a production environment(Win Server for C# parts + Linux Server for Redis)...

Answer (score 1):

This feels almost ideally what [MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx) was designed for.

Comment: I was also thinking the MSMQ on the above question.

Comment: Thanks! I think MSMQ would be well suited too.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is recoverable you can try a fast non-persistent NoSQL store.

Even better would be no shared data at all. Make the web service call into the Windows Server to request just the data that it needs right now. Maintaining shared state (for example in a database) is burdensome. If possible I'd avoid that entirely.

A very fast IPC mechanism would be WCF over named pipes.

Comment: your idea sounds quite good, but I don't understand..."Make the web service call into the Windows Server to request the data"...can you explain more? Thanks!